# Conectar android studio con un repositorio de git en un servidor de ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, git

Estoy llevando un curso en el cual nos pusieron llevar a cabo desarrollar una app con android studio. Nos piden crear un repositorio de git en un servidor de ubuntu (el cual tengo virtualizado) y que el código que desarrollo en android studio se guarde en ese repositorio (el android studio lo tengo instalado en la máquina física, no en la virtual). La pregunta es, como se puede lograr conectar el AS con un repositorio de git que esta en ese servidor de ubuntu virtualizado?

Answer (score -1):

Siguiendo la logica, creo que lo mas probable es que tengas que conectarte por ssh al server y copiar tu ssh-key, para después poder hacer un clone del repo en tu maquina física que es donde tienes android studio.
Te dejo un par de enlaces para que tengas una mejor idea de como hacerlo.
 Copiar key-ssh https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id

En caso de que ocupes algo acerca de clonear el repo, aqui te explican muy bien como hacerlo. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

PD: Copiar la llave ssh al server es para evitar introducir la contraseña de tu usuario cuando el server la pida, por cierto recuerda crear un usuario para tu maquina en el server y conectarte con ese usuario ya que por defecto linux toma el nombre de tu equipo para conectarse.